# Como fazer um Select de duas tabelas 1-N e retornar somente um registro da segunda?

Tags: mysql

Estou com dificuldade para criar um select que busca dados em duas tabelas, segue a descrição:

```
Tabela produto 
( 
  id_produto, 
  nome_produto, 
  preco, 
  categoria
)

Tabela imagem 
 ( 
   id_imagem, 
   id_produto, 
   nome_imagem, 
   caminho
)
```

Um produto pode ter varias imagens, mas o que eu preciso é selecionar 1 produto e a primeira imagem dele pois a primeira é a imagem a ser usada na divulgação.

Answer (score 1):

Use o `DISTINCT` para selecionar apenas a primeira imagem combinado com o `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT 
    NOME,
    CAMINHO
FROM
    PRODUTO
INNER JOIN IMAGEM ON IMAGEM.ID_PRODUTO = PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
AND
    IMAGEM.ID_PRODUTO = 1
ORDER BY
    IMAGEM.ID_PRODUTO
```

Comment: Mas ele só quer a primeira.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso te ajuda:

```
select 
  p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, p.preco, p.categoria, 
  i.id_imagem, i.id_produto, i.nome_imagem, i.caminho
from produto p
left join imagem i
on i.id_produto = p.id_produto
group by p.id_produto
order by p.id_produto
```

Comment: amigo, achei que alterando o limite me traria mais produtos, mas ele lista o mesmo produto mas com as outras imagens, como eu faria para pegar varios produtos com apenas uma imagem?

Comment: Editei a resposta... veja se ajuda.

Comment: isso aí amigo, muito obrigado. Caso eu queira pegar até 6 produtos aleatórios é só alterar o meu order by para "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6". certo?

Comment: @NilsonUehara, uma duvida o group by de um campo faz com que retorne somente uma linha das outras colunas ? e só um detalhe não precisa ter p.id_produto e i.id_produto no select se eles já são iguais.

Answer (score 0):

Algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM produto p
INNER JOIN imagem i ON p.id_produto = i.id_produto
GROUP BY p.id_produto
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um sub select para fazer o JOIN com um LIMIT 1

```
SELECT p.*, d.id_imagem, d.nome_imagem, d.caminho 
FROM PRODUTO p
JOIN 
(   select * from IMAGEM m
    where m.ID_PRODUTO = p.ID_PRODUTO
    ORDER BY m.ID_PRODUTO DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
D
on D.ID_PRODUTO = p.ID_PRODUTO
where p.ID_PRODUTO = 1 -- caso seja um produto especifico, se não remova .
```

Veja mais detalhes.

[mysql-inner-join-select-only-one-row-from-second-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526194/mysql-inner-join-select-only-one-row-from-second-table)